# VSCode Terminal - Clear Command Prompt

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm running on Linux.  I have the issue both in bash and pwsh shells.

How do I clear the current command prompt in the VS Code terminal?

For example, say you have copied and pasted a very long string into the terminal.

How do you clear what you just pasted?

The only way I know of for getting back to a an empty command prompt involves hitting backspace until you have deleted every character.

Is there any short cut for getting back to an empty prompt?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do you clear what you just pasted?

There is no command to clear what you have already pasted. You can do Ctrl + C or Ctrl+D to get the next promt.

Now if you want a short-cut to `clear` command which we use in terminal, its `Cmd + k` for Mac OS

Comment: Ctrl + C was what I was looking for.  This gets you back to an empty prompt so you start over.

Answer (score 0):

CTRL + shift + p, then write clear. You can use the clear command in bash terminal too.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only clears the previous output.  It does not clear out the text you typed into the current command.

Answer (score 0):

Use Console.Clear() in code.

or use 'cls' cmd on console